# What are the dangerous animals in Southern Nevada

Tags: safety, united-states, animals

I'm from Florida and I've only ever hiked in the Southeast US.

I don't know if I'm blind, but I can't find a listing of dangerous animals and their profiles. I tried [Nevada Dept of Wildlife](http://www.ndow.org/Nevada_Wildlife/Animals/) and [Southern Nevada Field Office - Dept of Fish & Wildlife](http://www.fws.gov/Nevada/las_vegas/index.htm).

I'm planning on hiking Red Rock Canyon and Valley of Fire later this month and I'm **not** planning on *seeking out* snakes, spiders or scorpions, but I would like to be able to identify them *just in case*.

I did take a look at [As an experienced backpacker in the Eastern US, what should I know before hiking in the Western US?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/226/as-an-experienced-backpacker-in-the-eastern-us-what-should-i-know-before-hiking)

as well as [Dealing with wildlife in the desert of California/Nevada in general and in the White Mountains in particular](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3914/dealing-with-wildlife-in-the-desert-of-california-nevada-in-general-and-in-the-w), but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I also checked out [What wild animals are there in California that can be dangerous or create hassles, and how do I avoid problems with them?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6026/what-wild-animals-are-there-in-california-that-can-be-dangerous-or-create-hassle), but I'm more concerned about the little guys.

I found *some* information on snakes in [Snake dangers while hunting in the desert?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/snake-dangers-while-hunting-in-the-desert])

Comment: The line, and stopped typing. I've already helped with what I can.

Comment: http://www.ndow.org/uploadedFiles/ndoworg/Content/Nevada_Wildlife/Animals/Concerns/NV_Ven_rept.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Quick List:**

- Mountain Lions
- Bobcats
- Coyotes
- Rattle Snakes
- Scorpions
- Feral Burros
- Feral Horses
- Desert Bighorn Sheep
- Black Widow Spiders

Red Rock Canyon & Valley of Fire have very heavy human visitation, so any large predators are likely to be scarce (**Mountain Lions** & **Bobcats**).

Coyotes are present, but unless cornered will not give you any problems.

The mostly likely encounter with 'dangerous' wildlife you might have would be with **Rattle Snakes**. There are several species, [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crotalus_cerastes) [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crotalus_mitchellii_stephensi) [aggressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crotalus_scutulatus) [than others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crotalus_oreganus_lutosus), found in the Mojave & Great Basin regions, although ***they are not very active during the colder winter months*** during which you are planning on visiting, however may seek out warm areas near humans. I have spent several years hiking & camping in the Mojave & have only ever come across exactly 3 rattlesnakes.

Also remember that rattle snakes will not always rattle, especially if cold.

There are several species of scorpions as well, however the stings of most are really no worse than a wasp sting, unless you have immune system issues or a particular sensitivity. (There are wasps too). The scorpion present in southern Nevada with the most potential for a deadly sting is the [**Arizona Bark Scorpion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arizona_bark_scorpion), it is to my knowledge not native, but I have found them in Las Vegas, most likely an introduced population or a lone hitchhiker. Note the wide body & coloring for identification. Scorpions are also not very active in colder months, however may seek out warm areas near humans as well.

[image: Arizona Bark Scorpion]

One animal with which people may get into trouble when they do not expect it, are the **[feral Burros](http://www.blm.gov/nv/st/en/fo/lvfo/blm_programs/blm_special_areas/red_rock_nca/red_rock_s_unique/burros_at_red_rock.html)** & **feral Horses** found in the Red Rock Canyon area. These animals are very accustomed to people & may approach hoping for food (don't feed them, it is against regulations), so they are generally not a threat, however, I have seen mother Burros react quite defensively when approached & their offspring are nearby. Aside from that, they may be prone to bite or kick if startled.

[image]

A similar caution should be taken with **Desert Bighorn Sheep**. Although you are unlikely to get near them, males will act aggressively if they feel they need to defend their herd.

**Black Widow spiders** & **Tarantulas** are also present. Though neither are actively aggressive towards humans.

One other thing to watch out for; the [**Teddy Bear Cholla**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindropuntia_bigelovii). If you have an unexpected encounter with one of these, you will not soon forget it! Bits of them will, shall we say *stick with you*.

Comment: You left out the most dangerous animal of them all.... **People**

Comment: You know @Erik, that reminds me; it is worth mentioning that there have been instances of cars being broken into when parked outside of the Red Rock Canyon loop on the side of SR-159 at various trail heads, so just be wary if especially if there are not many other vehicles around.

Comment: Hi Raystafarian; I went the other way, Las Vegas -> Florida. Been to Redrock Canyon a couple of times. The people are the biggest problem. Only time I hd a problem with an animal was when I  approached a bunch of Burros. I guess I thought back then that I was in some kind of petting zoo. As soon as we got close, the biggest one charged. Chased us back to the car where with huge teeth (flat like a grazing animal should have ) he bit the roof of the car before we sped away.